# How to use vimperator to interact with sites that use sub-menus?

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, submenu, vimperator

On sites that use a sub menus I find myself always having to use the mouse to hover/click the menu root to pull down the rest of the menu. How can I do this without having to use the mouse?

An [example](http://www.ornitocopter.net/v3-0-whats-new/) site on the "Morrowind Overhaul" link. When I use the `f` key to hit the link it goes to a different page rather than offering the sub-menu such as when you hover your mouse over it.

Another [example](http://www.primewire.ag) on the "Genre", "Section", and "Sort By" menus. When I use the `f` key on those it does nothing.

Comment: +1 on this.  Another good example is getting the hover text for xkcd. You might think that the focus and hover command ";;" from the extended hints mode will work; alas, not. I suspect what we're after is focus and hover in caret mode.

Answer (score 2):

It has [already been suggested in 2009](http://www.mozdev.org/pipermail/vimperator/2009-May/004341.html) to implement this feature.

Apparently, it has as of today not yet been implemented. In my case using `;;` to focus a hint doesn't work because it doesn't generate a [mouseover event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover).